# lightning:recordForm with lookup to Account Object does not work - Bug Identified (I believe)

Tags: lightning-record-form

**Final update**

See my answer below for the issues. I believe there is a bug in the implementation as well. The lookup will not work if the field is not on the page layout configuration.

> The weird part is, as long as *any* field that looks up to the same object is on the layout then the field you are actually using for the form does not have to be on the layout....

**Question for reference**

On a scratch org....

This is on a Lightning Tab NOT a record detail page. I am populating the recordId via attribute and it is working to get the record as the lookup to a custom object for the record is working. Only standard object lookups are not working.

Trying to build a simple form to populate an account lookup on a record. The Account object is supported according to the documentation but the following does not work:

**Markup - Nothing else exists. Sitting on a lightning tab**

```
<aura:component description="testcmp" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="theFields" type="List" default="
           ['Name','ns__Lookup_ToCustom__c', 'ns__Account__c']" />

    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                          recordId="{!v.theId}"
                          objectApiName="ns__CustomObject__c"
                          mode="edit" columns="2" fields="   
                          {!v.theFields}"
    >
<aura:component>
```

When the above is used the `ns__LookupToCustom__c` works just fine but the lookup to `Account` - `ns__Account__c` does not works and the following error is thrown in the console for the Account lookup field:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
    at wiredItems.c.map.a (lightning-lookup-desktop.js:2)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at U.wiredLookups (lightning-lookup-desktop.js:2)
    at r.dispatchEvent (aura_prod.js:3)
    at Object.next (force-wire-adapter.js:2)
    at W.next (force-lds-cache.js:2)
    at X.v (force-lds-cache.js:2)
    at subscriptions.size.subscriptions.forEach.t (force-lds-cache.js:2)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at X.emitValue (force-lds-cache.js:2)
```

System admin profile with access to the Account Field...APIVersion 43.0

All I am trying to do is a quick form with a lightning lookup and since there is no component to perform a lookup with typeahead etc this was a quick way to do it but.....

Anyone know of a way to get the lookup to the Account working?

**Note:** I added a contact lookup and tried that and the same thing happened. So happens on both account and contact

Images...

1. The first lookup is a lookup to a custom object and it works
2. The second lookup is to the account object and does not work, console shows above error

[image]
[image]

I tried to change the field list attribute to:

```
<aura:attribute name="theFields" type="String[]" default="Name,     
    ns__Lookup_ToCustom__c, ns__Account__c"/>
```

and the weird thing that happened is the Account lookup was removed from the form completely......

Thinking maybe something to do with a namespace custom object having a look up to a standard object?

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of error on with a Lightning custom component on a record page for opportunity.  My record page is cloned from the Salesforce default, and I placed the custom component in a tab in the main section.  The error I get with lookup fields in the custom component is `Cannot read property 'color' of undefined`.  When I place the lookup field on the page layout, then it works fine.

Comment: Salesforce support has confirmed that this is a bug.

Comment: Here is known issue link: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWoMQAW&title=lookup-field-value-is-missing-from-lightning-component-using-lightning-recordform-when-the-field-is-removed-from-the-page-layout

Comment: had a _similar_ issue with `lightning-record-edit-form` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, chalk this up to beta testing mac OS software.

**Answer**

The FLS for the lookup had read only checked true.

**Bug (I believe)**

- The field **or** *another field looking to the same object* **MUST** be on the layout.....

Unfortunately the beta of the new mac OS hides the checkboxes so I could not tell it was set to true....

Doh!

Thanks sanket for your answer. It got me to do some serious digging knowing that you found it working......

Comment: welcome :) I thought and asked the same earlier in comment, thank god finally you found it.

Comment: @sanketkumar - Yes you did but I could not see that the checkbox was checked. Not sure how it was set to read only.) so I was sure it was not checked (doh Thats what I get for beta testing an OS....Would have been helpful if a proper error message was shown though!

Answer (score 3):

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="contactfield" type="String[]" default="LastName,AccountId"/>    
    <Lightning:Card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" iconname="Standard:Contact"
                    title="quick contact">
    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="brokerForm"
                                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                objectApiName="Contact"
                                fields="{!v.contactfield}"
                                mode="edit"/>
    </Lightning:Card>
</aura:component>
```

This works for me. May be this recordId="{!v.theId}" is creating peoblem for you. Are you getting any error while adding component to layout?[image]

**Update**:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="Branchfield" type="String[]" default="Name,ACCOUNTCHILD__c,Account__c"/>    
<Lightning:Card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" iconname="Standard:Contact"
                title="quick Branch">
<lightning:recordForm aura:id="brokerForm"
                            recordId="a0T7F000006EEbPUAW"
                            objectApiName="Branch__c"
                            fields="{!v.Branchfield}"
                            mode="edit"/>
</Lightning:Card>
```

Here i tried with Lightning tab on custom object having a standard object and another with custom object lookup. Is that matching with you what you want? [image]

**Update:-**

I tried with custom Object having a namespace and working fine:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="Branchfield" type="list" default="['Name','sa_nket__ACCOUNTCHILD__c','sa_nket__Account__c']"/>    
<Lightning:Card class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" iconname="Standard:Contact"
                title="quick Branch">
<lightning:recordForm aura:id="brokerForm"
                            recordId="a0T7F000006EEbP"
                            objectApiName="sa_nket__Branch__c"
                            fields="{!v.Branchfield}"
                            mode="edit"/>
</Lightning:Card>
```

[image]

Comment: Just to comment while this may work for the person answering, this does not work for me in the scratch org